# How do I generate a WSDL file for my REST client?

Tags: python, rest, python-2.7

I wan't to generate a WSDL file for my REST web service. I also need to parse it in Python. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errr?

WSDL usually refers to SOAP which to my knowledge encapsulates the actual remote call protocol inside it's own protocol and just happens to use HTTP as a transport

REST refers to (usually) to using HTTP methods *appropriately* e.g. `DELETE /frobnication/1` would delete it `PUT /frobnication/1` would *completely replace* the thing (resource) under that URL. `POST /frobnication/1` updates it .... (HTTP does have a few more methods).

REST doesn't usually have a WSDL thou, IIRC, there is some talk about "commonly known entry points" (Google for that).

Vote me down but to me that question seems to mix up 2 completely different topics...

Answer (score 1):

> Until recently there was no formal language to describe Representational State Transfer (REST) Web services. But now there's WSDL 2.0!
>
> The publication of WSDL 2.0, which was designed with REST Web services in mind, as a World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) recommendation means there is now a language to describe REST Web services.

You can find more at [Describe REST Web services with WSDL 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/)